# Block indenting/un-indenting python code in vim

Tags: python, vim, pep8

I'm deciding to switch from tabs to spaces in my python code. Previously, if I wanted to indent/unindent a block of code in vim, I would use the `>>` or `<<` commands.

I'm using [the vimrc setup for python](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Misc/Vim/vimrc) by adding it to my `~/.vimrc`:

```
source ~/.vimrc-python
```

Currently, it appears it is setting new tabs to be 8 spaces wide, and when I block indent/un-indent it moves everything by four spaces.

How might I get everything so that it is consistent?

Comment: Good reference: http://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try these:

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
```

`shiftwidth` indicates how far to indent with the operations (`<<` and `>>`) you are using.

`tabstop` indicates how far to indent with the tab key.

`expandtab` converts tabs into spaces.

As [http://stackoverflow.com/users/2241874/bradd-szonye](Bradd Szonye) points out, you can also alternatively do

```
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=8
set expandtab
```

which means that if there is an actual `tab` character, it will show as 8 columns, but hitting the tab key gives 4 spaces.

Comment: Thanks! The file I've linked to has the `tabstop` set to 8, which is curious, as this is supposed to comply with the pep8 guidelines. It is also intended for C source, so I wonder if that is a compromise between the two.

Comment: I must admit I hadn't looked at your file. It looks like it tries to determine whether the file is written in C or in python, and change accordingly.  If you want to keep your tabs simple/consistent without considering the language, you can simply copy the three lines from my answer into your `~/.vimrc` and not use the linked file at all.

Comment: Yeah, I was doing this, but I do write in C occasionally, and thought this might be a good solution.

Comment: I would recommend leaving tabstop=8 and setting softtabstop=4 instead. That way, true tabs follow standard conventions, but the Tab key adds four spaces.

Comment: Thanks @BraddSzonye, I've included your advice.